# custom cell segue using button swift

Tags: swift, button, segue, cell

I have created custom cell with button inside. Now I am trying to pass a data via pressing on this button, but cant catch indexPath, need your help.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier=="editData"){
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destinationController = (segue.destinationViewController as! AddDetail)
            destinationController.info = data[indexPath.row]
                let nItem : Dealers = data [indexPath.row]
                destinationController.nItem = nItem
```

also Im trying do the same but from swiping menu:

```
           override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?{
          let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") {  (action, indexPath) in
          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addDealer", sender: self)
          let name = self.data [indexPath.row].dealerName

          print(name)
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

    return [delete, edit]
```

is it possible pass segue from swiping menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `indexPath` as the `sender` in `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addDealer", sender: indexPath)
```

then

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if let indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath {
     // then here you know what the indexPath was
     // and can do whatever you want with it
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry for maybe stupid question, what should be after? In my case                              "guard let row = (sender as? NSIndexPath)?.row else { return }"

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCell)` instead of `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`; you first extract `selectedCell` as your custom table view cell (`YourCustomTableViewCell` below):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
    if segue.identifier == "editData" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! AddDetail
        if let selectedCell = sender as? YourCustomTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCell)!
            destinationController.info = data[indexPath.row]
            let nItem : Dealers = data[indexPath.row]
            destinationController.nItem = nItem
        }
    }
}
```

As for the swiping question: I'll get back answer to this.

Comment: it is opening AddDetail form, but not passing values (nItem) to the form

Comment: @Rufat Note that it _does_ pass values (prior to "opening" the AddDetail view controller), see line : `destinationController.nItem = nItem`. (Property `nItem` of destination view controller, that is, `AddDetail` instance that is being "opened", get update to the local variable `nItem`, which has just been extracted from `data` by `let nItem : Dealers = data[indexPath.row]`.). However, it's difficult to help you out further without having a look at more of your code (your Q above just shows a stub).